# parse nested completion handlers

Tags: swift, asynchronous, parse-platform, completionhandler

I am trying to use a completion handler in a for loop.  The problem is that it will keep running the loop before the completion handler returns since it is an async call.  Attached is my code.  Do I need to use GCD?  I am new (obviously)to swift/ios.  Any advice would be much appreciated.  Bob

```
    for srcTerm in sFields {  //search using all search fields

        multiQuery (searchTerm: srcTerm)   {

            if srResult.count < self.lastValue {
                self.lastValue = srResult.count
                self.lastSearch = srcTerm
            }
        }
        // Do more stuff
    }


    func multiQuery (searchTerm: String,  completion: @escaping ([PFObject]) -> ()) {

        var exArray = [PFObject] ()
        let query = PFQuery(className: "searchLinks")

        do {

            query.whereKey("searchTerms", equalTo: searchTerm)

            query.findObjectsInBackground  (block: { (objects, error)-> Void in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Error Generated:  ",error)
                    return
                }
                if let objects = objects {
                   // do stuff
                }
                completion(self.srResult)
            })
        }
    }               // end of function
```

Comment: There are several ways to do it (Dispatch Groups, promises, etc.). Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/23112134/2124535

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GCD with nested Parse Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31347407/gcd-with-nested-parse-queries)

Comment: What do you want to do after all the queries are done ? The question/response linked above (the second one) seems like what you are looking for, eventhough the API has been updated a bit in Swift 3.

Comment: Could you provide a simple example of how to do this with GCD?  Thank so much.

Answer (score 2):

You could use DispatchGroups, here's an example (taken from https://medium.com/@wilson.balderrama/how-to-use-dispatchgroup-gdc-with-swift-3-35455b9c27e7. Similar to [GCD with nested Parse Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31347407/gcd-with-nested-parse-queries) but updated to Swift 3 API):

```
// Just a sample function to simulate async calls
func run(after seconds: Int, closure: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let queue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)
    queue.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(seconds)) {
        closure()
    }
}

let group = DispatchGroup()

group.enter()
run(after: 6) {
    print("Hello after 6 seconds")
    group.leave()
}

group.enter()
run(after: 3) {
    print("Hello after 3 seconds")
    group.leave()
}

group.enter()
run(after: 1) {
    print("Hello after 1 second")
    group.leave()
}


group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)) {
    print("All async calls were run!")
}
```

Using your code:

```
let group = DispatchGroup()

for srcTerm in sFields {  //search using all search fields
    group.enter()
    multiQuery (searchTerm: srcTerm) {
        if srResult.count < self.lastValue {
            self.lastValue = srResult.count
            self.lastSearch = srcTerm
        }
        group.leave()
    }
}

group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)) {
    // Do something after all async calls are done
}
```

Comment: Thanks nathan!  I did not realize its that simple.  Thank you.