# How can I check if all photos are uploaded to firebase before call performSegue

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am making a form to upload 3-4 photos to firebase storage.
After all photos are uploaded, I want to perform a segue

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "createClubToClubDetail", sender: self)
```

How can I check if all photos are uploaded to firebase before call performSegue.

Putting above line of code after `for` loop does not work because uploading photo run in different threads (?)

```
let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "xxxxx.appspot.com").child("club_photo").child(clubRef.key)

            for p in selectedImage {
                let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(p.value, 0.005)
                let storageImgRef = storageRef.child(p.key + ".jpg")
                storageImgRef.putData(imageData!, metadata: nil) { (metadata, error) in
                    if error != nil {
                        print(error!)
                        return
                    }
                    let downloadURL = metadata?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
                    var photoRef: DatabaseReference!
                    if p.key == "main" {
                            photoRef = ref.child("photo").child(clubRef.key).child("main")
                    }
                    if p.key == "sub1" {
                        photoRef = ref.child("photo").child(clubRef.key).child("sub1")
                    }
                    if p.key == "sub2" {
                        photoRef = ref.child("photo").child(clubRef.key).child("sub2")
                    }
                    if p.key == "sub3" {
                        photoRef = ref.child("photo").child(clubRef.key).child("sub3")
                    }

                    photoRef.setValue(downloadURL)
                    print("Upload photo: \(p.key)")


                }

            }


 self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "createClubToClubDetail", sender: self)
```

Comment: You could use `dispatch_group_enter()`, `dispatch_group_leave()` and do `self.performeSegue()` in `dispatch_group_notify()`.

Comment: Example in Swift: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45951107/parse-nested-completion-handlers/45951659#45951659. Also why use multiple if's instead if-elseif ? Negligible difference but still, you should break after the first match in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already mentioned, the standard `DispatchGroup` API is able to provide a nice solution to your issue.  Since it's very likely you might need this capability elsewhere in you app as well, I tried to encapsulate the `DispatchGroup` based solution in a nice *helper* class:

```
//
// UploadTracker.swift
//

import Foundation 
import FirebaseDatabase

class UploadTracker {
    private let group = DispatchGroup()

    fileprivate func trackSetValue(_ value: Any?, ref: DatabaseReference) {
        group.enter()
        ref.setValue(value) { (error, _) in
            assert(error != nil, "\(error)")
            self.group.leave()
        }
    }

    func uploadDidFinish(block: @escaping () -> Void) {
        group.notify(queue: .main) { block() }
    }
}

extension DatabaseReference {
    func setValue(_ value: Any?, trackedBy tracker: UploadTracker) {
        tracker.trackSetValue(value, ref: self)
    }
}
```

In your original code, the usage would then be:

```
let uploadTracker = UploadTracker()
for p in selectedImage {
    ...
    photoRef.setValue(downloadURL, trackedBy: uploadTracker)
}
uploadTracker.uploadDidFinish {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "createClubToClubDetail", sender: self)
}
```

Comment: in this code, if 1 photo is uploaded, then segue is called. I want all photo is uploaded, then call segue.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the below code for uploading multiple images and performing segue on the completion of last upload, though its a temporary fix but it works.

`saveToServerButtonPressed` method gets invoked when user wants to save the multiple images to firebase storage. `selectedImages` is the array of type `UiImage` and has all the images which user want to upload. `var counter` is kept just to capture the successful upload of the last image so that user can navigate to other screen/any other task which he wants to do only after all the uploads are done.

```
@IBAction func saveToServerButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    var counter = 0
    for image in selectedImages {
        uploadImage(image, progressBlock: { (progressValue) in
            self.progressStatus.text = "\(progressValue)%"
        }) { (downloadUrl, error) in
            if error == nil {
                if let downloadUrl1 = downloadUrl
                {
                    counter += 1
                    self.imagesUrls.append(downloadUrl1)
                    if counter == self.selectedImages.count {
                        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDownloadedSegue", sender: self)
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print("Error Occured \(String(describing: error))")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

method that actually upload the image on firebase

```
func uploadImage(_ image: UIImage, progressBlock: @escaping (_ percentage: Double) -> Void, completionBlock: @escaping (_ url: URL?, _ errorMessage: String?) -> Void) {
    let storage = FIRStorage.storage()
    let storageReference = storage.reference()
    let imageName = "\(Date().timeIntervalSince1970).jpg"
    let imagesReference = storageReference.child(imageName)

    if let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8) {
        let metadata = FIRStorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"
        let uploadTask = imagesReference.put(imageData, metadata: metadata, completion: { (metadata, error) in
            if let metadata = metadata {
                completionBlock(metadata.downloadURL(), nil)
            } else {
                completionBlock(nil, error?.localizedDescription)
            }
        })
        uploadTask.observe(.progress, handler: { (snapshot) in
            guard let progress = snapshot.progress else {
                return
            }
            let percentage = (Double(progress.completedUnitCount) / Double(progress.totalUnitCount)) * 100
            progressBlock(percentage)
        })
    } else {
        completionBlock(nil, "Image couldn't be converted to Data.")
    }
}
}
```

Note: This code runs well on Swift 4

Comment: saveToServerButtonPressed method gets invoked when user wants to save the multiple images to firebase storage. selectedImages is the array of type UiImage and has all the images which user want to upload. var counter is kept just to capture the successful upload of the last image so that user can navigate to other screen/any other task which he wants to do only after all the uploads are done.